# Analyzing input from an internal unit in fortran

Tags: string, io, floating-point, fortran

I'm using the fortran read function to analyze some input I've read from a file. I take a line, which is defined as,

```
character(len=128) :: line
```

And a valid input is if said line contains **exactly 3 floating point numbers**, divided by some separator. For example, `line='0.1 0.1 0.1'`. An invalid input would be `line='0.1 0.1'` or `line='0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1'` and so on.

To convert this string into numbers, I have used:

```
double precision :: nline(3)
read(line,*,iostat=err) nline
```

However, this successfully executes even if the original line contains more than 3 floats.
Is there a simple way to know if this input string exceeds the limit?

A nontrivial way would be to try and count separators in `line`, with something like `COUNT`, but I was hoping to avoid that.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour].

Comment: You need to use explicit format, not the `*` list-directed format. But then the column numbers are fixed so you need some more advanced parsing - first count the tokens, separate them and parse them individually.

Comment: Thanks @VladimirF. Is there any way to include the possibility that the internal separator could have some variability? For example, '0.1 0.1   0.1'... This is obviously a valid input, but if I count the number of tokens, I end up with too many.

Comment: @VladimirF MR&C says "An internal file may be used for list-directed I/O" (section 10.6 in the latest red edition, section 9.6 in the green edition)

Comment: @IanBush Of course it may, but then one gets the behaviour described in the question.

Comment: Sorry, misread your comment